# How to create a custom draggable rectangle overlay in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm trying to emulate a functionality in a certain app wherein a user can draw a rectangle and and hold & drag it. Then upon dragging, it shows the current length, width and area.

It's hard to put it in words so here's a GIF of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Can this be achievable with google maps api alone or are there any third-party libraries for this functionality?